# Set-Clipboard -Path - How do I find the version of PowerShell required?

Tags: powershell

I'm using this to set the file(s) to the clipboard:

```
Set-Clipboard -Path "C:\Users\username\Desktop\test1.txt"
Set-Clipboard -Path "C:\Users\username\Desktop\test2.txt" -Append
```

There's no info on the [MS site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Set-Clipboard?view=powershell-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-5.0) about this `-path` Parameter or when it was introduced.

I would like to know the version of PowerShell required for this command.

---

If I select the `Set-Clipboard` and press F1 in ISE it lists `-path` as a parameter but on the [help page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Set-Clipboard?view=powershell-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-5.0), it's not there.

Answer (score 2):

If I go visit the documentation you linked to, it says:

[image: The requested page is not available for powershell-5.0. You have been redirected to the newest product version this page is available for.]

So the explanation is likely that:

- Someone forgot to write and/or publish the documentation for `Set-Clipboard` in version 5.x (the one that comes with Windows 10), and
- The *newest version* (PowerShell 7.1) comes with a `Set-Clipboard` cmdlet that does NOT have a `-Path` parameter

---

If you want to see the actual parameters supported by each parameter set of a command at runtime, check out `Get-Command -Syntax` (this is the output I get in Windows PowerShell 5.1):

```
PS C:\> Get-Command Set-Clipboard -Syntax

Set-Clipboard [-Append] [-AsHtml] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]

Set-Clipboard [-Value] <string[]> [-Append] [-AsHtml] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]

Set-Clipboard -Path <string[]> [-Append] [-AsHtml] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]

Set-Clipboard -LiteralPath <string[]> [-Append] [-AsHtml] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: That page does work for me, strange! So you do have the `-Path` parameter. Cool. It looks like 5.0 is the version that it started on. if I try 4.0 it redirects me to 5.0. The 5.0 help page does have the `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` parameter whereas the 5.1 version doesn't so it seems the pages haven't been updated. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard?view=powershell-5.0

Comment: The pre-5.0 docs are incomplete, just because documentation for a specific version of a specific cmdlet isn't available doesn't mean it didn't exist. `Set-Clipboard` has been available since Windows PowerShell 3.0, and it _wouldn't surprise me if it had not changed during that time_ - but you'd need an installation of PowerShell 3.0 to confirm :-)

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, you mentioned that the `-Path` parameter is not available in 7.1? Why on earth would they remove that!

Comment: It's not so much that they _removed it_ - they _replaced the whole cmdlet_ with a new cross-platform version (and perhaps saw little value in the `-Path` parameter) - remember, the original was designed specifically for the clipboard API in **Windows**.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was sorted. No point in using this if it's going to be defunct later on.

Comment: @Ste That depends entirely on who/what you're developing for. If you're writing scripts specifically for Windows environments and know that they'll only be used in Windows PowerShell, then it won't be a problem

Comment: Yes, that's all I'll be doing. So you think I'd be good for a while to use this? I cannot find any info on when PS 7.1 will be shipped with Windows.

Comment: 5.1 is the last version of **Windows** PowerShell, so the answer is probably "never" :-) I wouldn't spend too much time worrying about what may or may not happen with a future version, write your code for what you have.

Comment: I suppose that's something that I'll have to worry about when the time comes. Thanks again. I've opened an issue for that on GitHub to see what the story is. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14758

Answer (score 0):

From the [first site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Set-Clipboard?view=powershell-7.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-5.0) you linked it appears that the minimum PowerShell version required to run the command `Set-Clipboard` (regardless of the `-Path` option) is **5.0**, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBble.png).

According to MS, versions below 5.0 should not work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. This has the `-path` parameter shown. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard?view=powershell-5.0

Comment: No, it says that version 5.0 is the newest version for which documentation exists on docs.msft _for that specific module_. `Set-Clipboard` was introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Run this you will find you answer:

```
Get-Help Set-Clipboard -Detailed
```

look for `-Path <String[]>` in the output:

SYNTAX

```
Set-Clipboard [-Append] [-AsHtml] [-Confirm] -LiteralPath <String[]> [-WhatIf] [<CommonParameters>]

Set-Clipboard [-Append] [-AsHtml] [-Confirm] -Path <String[]> [-WhatIf] [<CommonParameters>]

Set-Clipboard [-Value] <String[]> [-Append] [-AsHtml] [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [<CommonParameters>]
```

PARAMETERS

```
-Append [<SwitchParameter>]
    Indicates that the cmdlet does not clear the clipboard and appends content to it.
    
-AsHtml [<SwitchParameter>]
    Indicates that the cmdlet renders the content as HTML to the clipboard.
    
-Confirm [<SwitchParameter>]
    Prompts you for confirmation before running the cmdlet.
    
-LiteralPath <String[]>
    Specifies the path to the item that is copied to the clipboard. Unlike Path , the value of LiteralPath is used exactly as it is typed. No characters are interpreted as wildcards. 
    If the path includes escape characters, enclose it in single quotation marks. Single quotation marks tell Windows PowerShell not to interpret any characters as escape sequences.
    
-Path <String[]>
    Specifies the path to the item that is copied to the clipboard. Wildcard characters are permitted.
    
-Value <String[]>
    Specifies, as a string array, the content to copy to the clipboard.
    
-WhatIf [<SwitchParameter>]
    Shows what would happen if the cmdlet runs. The cmdlet is not run.
    
<CommonParameters>
    This cmdlet supports the common parameters: Verbose, Debug,
    ErrorAction, ErrorVariable, WarningAction, WarningVariable,
    OutBuffer, PipelineVariable, and OutVariable. For more information, see 
    about_CommonParameters (https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216).
```

Comment: Thanks but this really only tells me the parameters. I was looking the min version of PS required to run the command with the `-path` parameter.

Comment: @Ste Prior to PowerShell v5, the only way to copy to the clipboard was by using the clip.exe application. PowerShell V5 was the first time this was introduced. Ref: >> 
https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-copy-to-clipboard/

Comment: I was 99% sure clip.exe couldn't handle files in my research on how to do this. I've opened a Github in relation to both `-Path` and `-LiterallPath` not in version greater than 5.1 of PS. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14758. Because forwards compatibility was important to me too.